# Is there any connection between parents that prevents the father from impregnating different women?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was just asking myself if I could just place a single man into the barracks that "prepares" all the women to give birth?
So I can just use a useless dweller for this while all the productive men are still doing what they are good in?

Or will the women just block that guy as he has allready a child with... ?

Had no chance yet to check it by my self without getting into managment trouble.

Comment: Bonus points if you [dress him up as a pope](https://twitter.com/russpitts/status/611397478735347712/photo/1)... Holy breeder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, this is possible**! I've actually done that a couple of times.

In the beginning the focus is to make a lot of babies as fast as possible but later you might **start to use `sex` as a tool for making people happier**; so at that time it doesn't really make sense just to keep someone there as a main/single stallion. Instead, you **start training dwellers with low stats** and **send unhappy people to the `house of love`**.

Comment: I think the baby has similar stats to the parents, so useless dwellers make more useless dwellers.

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 I don't know, it might be random, based on experience... nevertheless, almost all dwellers that you create are pretty useless in the beginning... I mean they have at most 3 on 1 or 2 categories, and that's rare... That's why you train them... When you reach 60 or 70 dwellers, you need very good people...

Comment: How I play is: after 10 more people in the vault, each room's minim specific stat is increased by 1. At the moment, to work in a diner, you need at least 6 Agility :) . You have to be trained extensively to work in my diners :D

Comment: Having good stats in one or both parents can have a small effect on children, but it's on the order of 2-3 points maybe 4 if you're lucky...Might as well just pick a high Charisma stallion so they start dancing faster.